# Create a symbolic link relative to the current directory

Tags: directory, symlink, ln

I'm trying to create a symbolic link in my home directory that points to a directory on my external HDD.

It works fine when I specify it like this:

```
cd ~
ln -s /run/media/name/exhdd/Data/ Data
```

However it creates a faulty link when I try this:

```
cd /run/media/name/exhdd
ln -s Data/ ~/Data
```

This creates a link that I cannot `cd` into.

When I try, bash complains:

```
bash: cd: Data: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

The Data symbolic link in my home is also colored in red when `ls` is set to display colored output.

Why is this happening? How can I create a link in that manner? (I want to create a symlink to a directory in my working directory in another directory.)

---

**Edit:** according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104384) StackOverflow answer, if the second argument (in my case that'd be ~/Data) already exists and is a directory, `ln` will create a symlink to the target *inside* that directory.

However, I'm experiencing the same issue with:

```
ln -s Data/ ~/
```

Comment: Just a random tip: `cd ~` is usually the same as `cd`.

Comment: `ls -l ~/Data` would have helped you see what was wrong with the "red" link.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that I could do that, thanks. I remember trying to `cat` it, but I forgot what was the result... (I'm not home at them moment.)

Comment: Side note, suppose you want to only create a symlink of all files, dir and subdir inside a particular folder, say, all items inside `/run/media/name/exhdd/Data/` to `Data` then use the following `ln -s /run/media/name/exhdd/Data/* Data`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Here's what's happening. If you make a symlink with a relative path, the symlink will be relative. Symlinks just store the paths that you give them. They never resolve paths to full paths. Running

```
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ ln -s ls /usr/bin/ls2
```

creates a symlink named `ls2` in `/usr/bin` to `ls`(viz. `/usr/bin/ls`) relative to the directory that the symlink is in (`/usr/bin`). The above command would create a functional symlink from any directory.

```
$ pwd
/home/me
$ ln -s ls /usr/bin/ls2
```

If you moved the symlink to a different directory, it would cease to point to the file at `/usr/bin/ls`.

You are making a symlink that points to `Data`, and naming it `Data`. It is pointing to itself. You have to make a symlink with the absolute path of the directory.

```
ln -s "$(realpath Data)" ~/Data
```

Answer (score 20):

I was having the same problem. Google led to this answer but the simplest solution is not documented here:

```
ln -sT
```

-T does the trick

man ln:

```
-T, --no-target-directory
    treat LINK_NAME as a normal file always
```

Just adding this here so anyone with the same question may find this :)

Answer (score 17):

`ln`'s behavior with relative paths is unintuitive. To restore sanity, use the `-r` flag.

```
cd /run/media/name/exhdd
ln -sr Data/ ~/Data
```

Explanation:

```
   -r, --relative
          create symbolic links relative to link location
```

What it means is that `ln` will do what you expect. It will take into account what directory you are in, what directory the target is in, and construct a path relative to the directory the link will be in. The default behavior (without `-r`) is to interpret the first parameter (target) *literally*, in which case you have to construct the path yourself so that it is valid at the link's directory.

Alternatively, use an absolute path, as mentioned by @SmithJohn

```
ln -s "$(realpath Data)" ~/Data #bash shell
```

or

```
ln -s "(realpath Data)" ~/Data #fish shell
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simply you can create link for a folder. Look my command

ln -s /home/targatedfolder /var/www/html/link_name